# Probability to sample one member of each class inside a population

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling

I am working on a data science project which is slowly turning into a mathematical problem :
To keep things short, I have a population of size $A$. This population contains $C$ classes and we know the distribution of those classes inside the population (i.e. for each class we know the probability to get one member of this class, if we sample one element from $A$ : $p_1, ... p_C$).

Now, at the start of an algorithm I made, I sample $n$ elements from $A$ and I have observed that the outcome of the algorithm depends greatly on this initial sampling : If I have at least one element of each class in my initial sampling, my algorithm will do great. If one or more classes are not represented in my initial sampling, my algorithm will perform poorly.

Given that I am free to choose whichever $n$ I see fit, I would like to know which one to choose to be "sure" to choose at least one element from each class given $A$, $C$, and $p_1, ... p_C$.

Because I will have to work on several dataset, I would like to know if there is a way to find $n$, given any population size $A$, any number of classes $C$ and any distribution $p_1, ... p_C$. Is there a way to do so ?

It looks like some kind of reverse birthday problem. I have started looking at ways to solve this problem using combinatorics but I don't see any easy way to find a general solution.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Short answer: there is no guaranteed $n$ other than greater than (population size - size of smallest class) since with a smaller $n$ and  bad luck you  could pick everyone from outside that class. There is mathematics that will tell you the probability of missing a class as a function of $n$. With increasing $n$ you can reduce that probability.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ethan, what are the mathematics you're talking about ? I'll be fine with a probability below 20% to miss a class but I just don't know how to compute it.

Comment: It seems more like the coupon collector problem than the birthday problem, and I think converges to the coupon collector problem as $A$ increases without bound.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the total population is $N$, partitioned into $C$  classes with sizes $N_i$ (so $N = N_1 + \cdots + N_C$). We choose $n$ points at random. We want the probability that we have at least one from each class.

The total number of samples of size $n$ is $\binom{N}{n}$.

We can choose one from each class $N_1 N_2 \cdots N_C$ ways, and then choose the remaining points from the remaining population in $\binom{N-C}{n-C}$ ways. So the probability that we have at least one from each class is
$$
\frac{N_1 N_2 \cdots N_C \binom{N-C}{n-C}}{\binom{N}{n}} .
$$

Note: Fixed in response to OP's correction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, I found a wrong result for your formula for the example I have : N = 150, C = 3, $N_i$ = 50 and n = 5. (Result is > 2...). But $\frac { C \times N _ { 2} \cdots N _ { C } \left( \begin{array} { l } { N-C } \\ { n-C } \end{array} \right) } { \left( \begin{array} { l } { N } \\ { n } \end{array} \right) } \\$ seems to be a better answer (I get 0.16 which is close to experimental results), however I have no idea which $N_i$ to take out of the equation. I suppose taking the biggest one out would give me a lower bound...

Comment: That's just the kind of error I was afraid I might have made. I just edited to fix the formula. (I think you meant $N_1$ instead of $C$ in the product.

Comment: I tried a lot of experiments with small cases (like [X, X, X, Y, Z] for example) and your last formula seems correct. However for large numbers, I keep getting wrong results (probabilities > 1). For N = 150, C = 3, $N_i$ = 50 and n = 5, I get a result > 2 while I should get a result somewhere around 0.63 (experimental results obtained after sampling 10000 times)